# restrict_chat_memeber and chat type

Tags: aiogram

-------- **QUSTION 1**

I tried so many times to mute user for a time in a group.

```py
can_send_message = False
await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, user_id, permissions=can_send_message)
```

As you see there is a problem, it is not working, I read the documentation, but I still didn't understand how to do it

---

------- **QUESTION 2**

```py
# @bot.message_handler(commands=['balance'], func=lambda message: message.chat.type in ['private', 'group', 'supergroup'])
@router.message(Command('balance'))
```

As you can see, the there is a 2 lines of code, in the first line you see a code on **"telebot"** library, and on the second you see **"aiogram"** code. So, I don't know how to do the same, get messages only in **['private', 'group', 'supergroup']**